# What do you call Xo-Y words? (ex: Judeo-Christian)

Tags: terminology

Is there a special name to call words like *Judeo-Christian*, following the construction `Xo-Y`?

*([Same question for French](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/1816))*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, this kind of word is called a *[compound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_%28linguistics%29#Noun.E2.80.93noun_compounds)*. Wikipedia says:

> *Compounding* or *Word-compounding* refers to the faculty and device of language to form new words by combining or putting together old
>   words. In other words, compound, compounding or word-compounding
>   occurs when a person attaches two or more words together to make them
>   one word. The meanings of the words interrelate in such a way that a
>   new meaning comes out which is very different from the meanings of the
>   words in isolation.

The specific construction in your example (and in your French examples as well) takes a *[combining form](http://www.wordnik.com/words/combining%20form)* `Xo` (*Judeo* is the combining form of *Jewish*) and compounds it with a noun `Y`.

This is an example of a specific type of compound known as a *[classical compound](http://www.enotes.com/topic/Classical_compound)*.

Comment: Is there a specific term if it's more than just a compound? If it's also a modifier, eg semi-precious

Comment: @MartinBeckett I expanded my answer as I peeked at the OP's French question and saw that they were all of this specific form.

Comment: "This is an example of a specific type of compound known as a classical compound". Does that imply *classical compound* is not limited to the Xo-Y pattern?

Comment: @Kris Yes; read the reference I [linked](http://www.enotes.com/topic/Classical_compound).

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but I'm surprised no-one mentioned "hyphenated". The construction described in the OP is a [hyphenated compound word.](http://englishplus.com/grammar/00000127.htm)

Comment: The question asks for a "special name" for words "following the construction Xo-Y".  "Hyphenated compound word" is a hypernym of "classical compound", a term that takes in combinations where a vowel "facilitates the combination", like "the Greek thematic vowel -o-" or  "the Latin thematic -i-".  That is, both terms are correct but "classical compound" is more specific than "hyphenated compound".

Comment: Thank you. I missed the nuance of the "o" in "Xo-Y". I learned something!