# What is the combining form of 'Christian?'

Tags: single-word-requests, prefixes, compounds

I recently heard the term 'Judeo-Christian' which caused a thought to strike me. I don't know how to switch the order of the [classical compound](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/52160/52574) (word).

What is the [combining form](https://www.wordnik.com/words/combining%20form) of 'Christian?'

Before I posted this, I searched for an answer in the entry of 'Christian' of Merriam-Webster and Googled "(what is the) combining form of christian."

Comment: I can't think of an example where it is used, but I would have thought 'Christo'.

Comment: 'What is the combining form' implies that the bound morpheme exists. Such words might well be useful, and may well come to exist, but I can't find any. To quote Cerberus: 'The point of productivity is not that you can add [an affix] to any word you please, but that it can be added to some words to create new words.'  I'd suggest that WS2's offering might well be taken as 'relating to Christ', as in 'Christology'.

Comment: @medica (1) No, I didn't specifically "attempt to google 'Christo-'", but I did "at least the most rudimentary of work before asking here" such as checking for my answer in the Merriam-Webster entry for "Christian" and Googling "(what is the) combining form of christian". (2) You make the assumption that I'm supposed to have searched for "Christo-" and not something else like "Christi-". Why? (3) What do you expect me to read in the help section?

Comment: It's entirely wholly bizarre that this question was voted down. I've already learned what a "combining form" is, and thanks to WS2's answer I now know it is "Christo-" in this case.  And more!  It seems way too advanced for ELL, so it's hard to see why it is not a Well Regarded question here.

Comment: ah!  the word editor thing ruined my "Holy" joke

Comment: I agree and find @medica (and downvoters/closers) far too harsh. If you do not know what to look for, then it is not easy to look for it...

Comment: @mplungjan - you are correct.

Comment: @Kris I would place the question mark outside the quote marks in the title. I think you should do it (I'm not being sarky).

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'd (and did) too, but I've grown tired of fighting overzealous Stack Exchange editors.

Comment: It's your question, you can make as many edits as you want. Kris and I have "history" and most probably Kris didn't want to admit I am right. C'est la vie, and who cares about overzealous SE editors! (but usually we do a good job :))

Answer (score 3):

"Christo-" may be technically correct, as per the other answer, (even though I can't think of any words which use it), but I think in day-to-day speech a native speaker would be more likely to use "Christiano-" if they needed to invent a word on the spot.

For example *(politics aside, talking only about usage)*: the word "Islamophobia" is gaining a lot of traction these days, and (very) occasionally you hear people talking about "Christianophobia" alongside it. Such as in the [title of this book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Christianophobia-A-Faith-Under-Attack/dp/1846042755).

EDIT: I wrote this in a comment, I think it's worth adding to my main answer:

I think the real answer to the original question is "there isn't one", or "it depends". We're trying to look for the "correct" word based on obscure etymological rules, but most native speakers won't know those rules or care about them and there's very few contexts where we'd need to use a "combining form"

Comment: What about "Christendom" ?

Comment: Yep, that word is well-known, but using "Christen-" in another context ("Christenphobia"?) doesn't sound right to me. I think the real answer to the original question is "there isn't one", or "it depends". We're trying to look for the "correct" word based on obscure etymological rules, but most native speakers won't know those rules or care about them and there's very few contexts where we'd need to use a "combining form" of *Christian* anyway.

Comment: A great point - the "real answer" is there isn't one, or just "Christian" per se

Answer (score 2):

Christo-, per Oxford Dictionaries (not OED), is the combining form for that which relates to Christ e.g. *Christocentric.*

Comment: But perhaps more relevantly, 'Christen-' occurs in 'Christendom'. 'Relating to Christianity' and 'relating to Christ' are not as synonymous as they ought to be.

Comment: so how come it's not "Christen-" then?

Comment: Not to confuse between *Christ* and *Christian.* The Q is not about a combining form for *Christ.*

Answer (score 2):

Right off hand, I do not have a canonical (no pun intended) answer to this, but can say this much, which should be pretty much obvious to anyone:

*Christian* is a noun-form use of what is essentially an adjective. As such, we cannot have a combining (o-) form of it.

*Christian* itself is sufficient in the function for combinations as it is already an adjective.

Whence,
*Christian-Jewish,* *Christian-Judaic* perhaps?  (depending on context, as required.)